Cookies are being received in `Set-Cookie` header but not being set in browser
gTalk is a whatsapp-inspired messaging web app that I'm trying to build. On the backend there's an express server (hosted on render.com), and the front end is Next.js 14 (hosted on vercel).
On the login page when the correct credentials are passed the backend sends a 'login successful' response and sets up two cookies. One is an httpOnly cookie that has a JWT token, while the other called "userInfo" has some generic user info like name and email. Once the cookie is set the user is redirected to the /chat route, and all non-auth routes are protected by the middleware which checks whether the "userInfo" cookie exists or not, and if it doesn't then redirects the user to the /login route.
The problem is that while I'm getting both the cookies in the Set-Cookie header, the browser is not setting those cookies. I've looked through many answers and articles, and I believe I've done all the necessary things like:
01. Adding the client url to the list of cors origin in the express server.
02. Adding sameSite: "none" and secure: true to the cookies. (Also httpOnly: true to the token cookie.)
03. Making the requests using credentials: "include" option in the fetch request.
Following is the relevant code.
auth.ts (express server auth route for login):
//login
authRouter.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  // get email and password from body
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  console.log(email, password);
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "user not found, email might be incorrect" });
  }

  const isPasswordValid = await compareHash(password, user.password);

  if (isPasswordValid) {
    // generate JWT with user id
    const token = await generateToken(user._id.toString());

    // set cookie with httpOnly flag
    res.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    });

    // set regular object containing user info:
    // { firstName, lastName, email }
    const userInfo = {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
    };

    res.cookie("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo), {
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    });

    return res.status(200).json({ message: "login sucessful" });
  }

  res.status(400).json({ message: "incorrect password" });
});

verifyJWT.ts (it's a middleware to check the validity of the token passed using httpOnly cookie):
import express from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

// we need to extend the default type so typescript
// will stop complaining
interface CustomRequest extends express.Request {
  userId?: string;
}

export default function verifyJWT(
  req: CustomRequest,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) {
  // Check if req.cookies is defined
  if (!req.cookies) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized: No cookies sent" });
  }

  // extract token from cookie
  const token = req.cookies.token;

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized: No token" });
  }

  try {
    // verify token using secret key
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET!);

    req.userId = (decodedToken as { userId: string }).userId;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized: Invalid token" });
  }
}

loginUser (function that logs the user in):
async function loginUser(data: FieldValues, setError: any, router: any) {
  // convert FieldValues object into an array of key-value pairs
  const dataArray = Object.entries(data);

  // extract form data
  const { email, password } = Object.fromEntries(dataArray) as {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  };

  console.log(email, password);

  // signup user
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_API_URL!}/login`, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });

    if (res.status === 400) {
      const errorData = await res.json();
      setError("root", { message: errorData.message });
      return;
    }

    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);

    // redirect user to `/chat`
    router.push("/chat");
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.message === "Failed to fetch") {
      setError("root", {
        message: "We failed to log you in. Please try again later.",
      });
    }
    console.log(error);
  }
}

What mistake am I making here? Even a hint would be extremely useful.
Live: g-talk.vercel.app
Complete code: Client, Server
Test credentials:
Email: naruto@mail.com
Password: konoha
